# Sequelize trying to associate User and Roles (mysql2)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, associations, mysql2

I am trying to associate User and Roles so I can give a user a role. I keep on getting an error when I try to add a user, without the association it will work, but I want to associate them.

here is my User model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("User", {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        last_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        img_src: DataTypes.STRING,
        //updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        status: { 
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 1
        },
        //active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'user'
    });
    User.associate = (models) => {
        User.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'role_id'})};
        
    return User;
}
```

here is my Role model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
        role_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'role',
        initialAutoIncrement: 2000
    });
    Role.associate = (models) => {
        Role.hasMany(models.User, { as: 'users', foreignKey: 'user_id' })};

    return Role;
}
```

when I try to add a user, here is the error I get in my terminal

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`e2e-react-db`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`role_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: I don't think you have to associete the Role with the User, do the Oposite on User model:
```User.associate = (models) => {
        User.hasOne(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })};```

Comment: @ThiagoRobles it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Alrigth, thinking this better, I guess that the best way to do this is to add a new column on User model called `role_id` , and the association:
```User.associate = (models) => { User.hasOne(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'role_id' })};```

Remove all the Other associations. and I advise you to revert all migrations, make these changes that I said, and run the migrations again

Comment: Alright, so I'll awnser the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the best way to do this is to add a new column on User model called role_id , and the association:

```
User.associate = (models) => { User.hasOne(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'role_id' })};
```

Remove all the Other associations. and I advise you to revert all migrations, make these changes that I said, and run the migrations again